# SonarQube Scanner fails with “Not inside a git worktree” error

Tags: c#, git, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm using Travis CI to run SonarQube Scanner on a `C#` project. I've managed to get the scanner to work once but it failed with no obvious reason on the next commit (the commit updated `README.md`).

I've tried to clear the build cache, with no success. I've also read about the issue in other programming languages (Java mainly) but no luck so far.

### Error log

The specific error is:

`Not inside a Git work tree: /home/travis/build/presque-fini`

The full error log is below:

```
34.72s$ mono ./scanner/SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end -d:sonar.login="tkoen"
SonarScanner for MSBuild 4.9
Using the .NET Framework version of the Scanner for MSBuild
Post-processing started.
WARNING: The following projects do not have a valid ProjectGuid and were not built using a valid solution (.sln) thus will be skipped from analysis...
/home/travis/build/presque-fini/nez/Nez.Portable/Nez.csproj
WARNING: File '/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/MonoGame/v3.0/Assemblies/DesktopGL/x86/SDL2.dll' is not located under the root directory '/home/travis/build/presque-fini' and will not be analyzed.
WARNING: File '/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/MonoGame/v3.0/Assemblies/DesktopGL/x64/SDL2.dll' is not located under the root directory '/home/travis/build/presque-fini' and will not be analyzed.
WARNING: File '/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/MonoGame/v3.0/Assemblies/DesktopGL/x86/soft_oal.dll' is not located under the root directory '/home/travis/build/presque-fini' and will not be analyzed.
WARNING: File '/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/MonoGame/v3.0/Assemblies/DesktopGL/x64/soft_oal.dll' is not located under the root directory '/home/travis/build/presque-fini' and will not be analyzed.
WARNING: File '/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/MonoGame/v3.0/Assemblies/DesktopGL/x86/libSDL2-2.0.so.0' is not located under the root directory '/home/travis/build/presque-fini' and will not be analyzed.
WARNING: File '/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/MonoGame/v3.0/Assemblies/DesktopGL/x64/libSDL2-2.0.so.0' is not located under the root directory '/home/travis/build/presque-fini' and will not be analyzed.
WARNING: File '/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/MonoGame/v3.0/Assemblies/DesktopGL/x86/libopenal.so.1' is not located under the root directory '/home/travis/build/presque-fini' and will not be analyzed.
WARNING: File '/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/MonoGame/v3.0/Assemblies/DesktopGL/x64/libopenal.so.1' is not located under the root directory '/home/travis/build/presque-fini' and will not be analyzed.
WARNING: File '/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/MonoGame/v3.0/Assemblies/DesktopGL/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib' is not located under the root directory '/home/travis/build/presque-fini' and will not be analyzed.
WARNING: File '/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/MonoGame/v3.0/Assemblies/DesktopGL/libopenal.1.dylib' is not located under the root directory '/home/travis/build/presque-fini' and will not be analyzed.
WARNING: File '/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/MonoGame/v3.0/Assemblies/DesktopGL/MonoGame.Framework.dll.config' is not located under the root directory '/home/travis/build/presque-fini' and will not be analyzed.
The SONAR_SCANNER_HOME environment variable is not required and will be ignored.
Calling the SonarQube Scanner...
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /home/travis/build/presque-fini/presque-game/scanner/sonar-scanner-4.3.0.2102/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: /home/travis/build/presque-fini/presque-game/.sonarqube/out/sonar-project.properties
INFO: SonarScanner 4.3.0.2102
INFO: Java 11.0.2 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
INFO: Linux 4.15.0-1028-gcp amd64
INFO: User cache: /home/travis/.sonar/cache
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /home/travis/build/presque-fini/presque-game/scanner/sonar-scanner-4.3.0.2102/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: /home/travis/build/presque-fini/presque-game/.sonarqube/out/sonar-project.properties
INFO: Analyzing on SonarCloud
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8" (analysis is platform dependent)
INFO: Load global settings
INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=706ms
INFO: Server id: 1BD809FA-AWHW8ct9-T_TB3XqouNu
INFO: User cache: /home/travis/.sonar/cache
INFO: Load/download plugins
INFO: Load plugins index
INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=165ms
INFO: Load/download plugins (done) | time=22322ms
INFO: Loaded core extensions: developer-scanner
INFO: Process project properties
INFO: Execute project builders
INFO: Execute project builders (done) | time=49ms
INFO: Project key: presque-fini_presque-game
INFO: Base dir: /home/travis/build/presque-fini
INFO: Working dir: /home/travis/build/presque-fini/presque-game/.sonarqube/out/.sonar
INFO: Load project settings for component key: 'presque-fini_presque-game'
INFO: Load project settings for component key: 'presque-fini_presque-game' (done) | time=227ms
INFO: Found an active CI vendor: 'TravisCI'
INFO: Load project branches
INFO: Load project branches (done) | time=136ms
INFO: Check ALM binding of project 'presque-fini_presque-game'
INFO: Detected project binding: BOUND
INFO: Check ALM binding of project 'presque-fini_presque-game' (done) | time=122ms
INFO: Load project pull requests
INFO: Load project pull requests (done) | time=141ms
INFO: Load branch configuration
INFO: Load branch configuration (done) | time=4ms
INFO: Load quality profiles
INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=156ms
INFO: Load active rules
INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=3676ms
INFO: Organization key: presque-fini
INFO: Indexing files...
INFO: Project configuration:
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 33.193s
INFO: Final Memory: 7M/27M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
ERROR: Not inside a Git work tree: /home/travis/build/presque-fini
ERROR: 
The SonarQube Scanner did not complete successfully
13:29:46.773  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
The command "mono ./scanner/SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end -d:sonar.login="token"" exited with 1.
```

### System config

- CI: Travis (you can browse the full build here: https://travis-ci.com/github/presque-fini/presque-game/builds/172666297)
- OS: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
- Git 2.21.0
- Versions used: `sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.9.0.17385-net46`
- Scanner command: `mono ./scanner/SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end -d:sonar.login="token"`
- Project hosted on Github (https://github.com/presque-fini/presque-game)

Comment: This issue is linked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49257285/sonarqube-jenkins-git-integration-when-cloning-to-a-subdirectory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## What's the problem?

The problem is caused by the fact that when Travis clones your project, it clones it in a sub-directory named after the repo name (`presque-game` in your case). This will give you the following structure:

```
organization-name/repo-name
```

When you launch the analysis, it starts by default in the `organization-name` folder and not in the `repo-name` sub-folder. Because `organization-name` is not a git repo, Sonarcloud fails.

## How can I solve it?

To resolve this problem, you need to set the analysis property `sonar.projectBaseDir`:

```
-d:sonar.projectBaseDir="repo-name/"
```

This will give you this full command (the path is absolute, just to be sure, but I guess a relative path will work too):

```
mono ./scanner/SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin -k:"presque-fini_presque-game" -o:"presque-fini" -d:sonar.login="token" -d:sonar.projectBaseDir="/home/travis/build/presque-fini/presque-game/"
```

---

References:

- [SonarCloud docs, Alternate analysis section](https://sonarcloud.io/documentation/analysis/scan/sonarscanner/#alternate-analysis-directory):

  > If the files to be analyzed are not in the directory where the analysis starts from, use the sonar.projectBaseDir property to move analysis to a different directory.
- SonarQube community question : [SonarQube Scanner fails with “Not inside a git worktree” error](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarqube-scanner-fails-with-not-inside-a-git-worktree-error/26914)